# IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0 while loading Bitmap from View

Tags: java, canvas, view, bitmap, imageview

I'm trying to draw on an ImageViewTouch, a library which enables pinch zooming. I'm able to draw over the image using Canvas, but when I zoom the image, the drawing disappears.

For this, I'm trying to convert the view to a bitmap and set theImageBitmap for this same view. Here's the code:

```
mImage.setDrawPath(true);
mImage.setImageBitmap(loadBitmapFromView(mImage)); 

public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getWidth(), v.getHeight());
        v.draw(c);
        return b;
}
```

When I do this, I get the following log error:

```
07-11 21:13:41.567: E/AndroidRuntime(20056): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
07-11 21:13:41.567: E/AndroidRuntime(20056):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:638)
07-11 21:13:41.567: E/AndroidRuntime(20056):    at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:620)
```

If I remove the `loadBitmapFromView` call the drawing normally appears over the image. When I try to do any interaction with the image (like zooming in or out), the drawing disappears, remaing only the background image, which is a picture.

--- EDIT ---

Here's some more code placed after the `loadBitmapFromView` call. The case is: I have a radio group listenner and when I check some radio button, I have to load the image and draw some possibles drawings over it.. then I'm trying to convert everything (the image and the drawings) into only one bitmap.

Here's the ohter part of the code:

```
bitmap = BitmapUtils.decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(root + DefinesAndroid.CAMINHO_SHOPPINGS_SDCARD + nomeImagemAtual, size.x, size.y);
mImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

After that, I draw everything I have to draw and try to convert the view to bitmap using the loadImageBitmap method I have shown.

the `decodeSampledBitmapFromResource` method I got from this link on android developers http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I finally figured out a solution for my problem.

I'm using the `post` method of the View, which will be executed only after the view measuring and layouting, this way `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` returns the actual width and height.

Here's the code sample:

```
mImage.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mImage.setImageBitmap(loadBitmapFromView(mImage));
    }
});
```

Hope it also helps someone else :)

Comment: Hi, can you explain a little more. So wherever you set your image bitmap, you just put it in a `Runnable` like above and your width and height were no issues anymore?

Comment: Code is working for all the Android API's rather than API 21(lollipop). I am working with Samsung S4 device but these line of code also didn't help me.

Answer (score 10):

If everything else is correct you are executing your code too early.

The view's layout has not yet been measured by Android. Try executing in OnResume just to see if this is your problem.

Cheers!

Comment: I may be doing what you said cause right before calling this setImageBitmap I call another one. I have edited the question with some more explanations!

Comment: I don't get when you say try executing in OnResume.. I set the bitmap on the radio button change listener, the activity is still the same :( could you please try to ilustrate it by showing me some piece of code? thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            loadBitmapFromView(mImage);
        }
    }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0` is because in your `Bitmap.createBitmap()` call `v.getLayoutParams().width` or `v.getLayoutParams().height` is 0. Probably the `LayoutParams` are wrongly set in `mImage`.

Update: `setLayoutParams()` for the `mImage` before using `createBitmap()`. Something like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(30, 30);
mImage.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: Yes.. I have checked, they are really zero.. but why? I'm just passing the view I had before as parameter, but now this view has the canvas drawn on it

Comment: @FelipeMosso are you passing the view before or after it's been presented to the user? IIRC, if you pass it before, then the `getLayoutParams().height` and `getLayoutParams().width` will be 0.

Comment: I'm passing before it's been presented to the user.. cause I have to present him with all the drawings already drawn. I have edited the question with more information, take a look at it,pls :)

Comment: How can I pass it after present it to the user? I'm really stuck :(

Comment: Please see my update. If it doesn't help, please post all the code which touches `mImage`.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I forgot to set `orientation` to `vertical` for parent `LinearLayout` and the default value of `horizontal` has been set, so I set it and my problem gone...

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it relates to this specific question , but I had the same error and I solved it with getting a image source , in the layout xml file ,  from drawable instead of from mipmap (of course I had to put the image there before).