# xhdpi to ldpi resource scaling

Tags: android, drawable

I use `xhdpi` resources in my app and let the system scale them to other `dpi`s.
Among the other resources I have 1px wide png file as stretch background for a view.
The problem is that I received some crush reports from `ldpi` device users (like Galaxy Pocket) with the error like

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:603)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:551)
at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:437)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:649)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:624)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:775)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1974)
... 34 more
```

As I understand, my 1px wide png is causing this problem. 1 px in `xhdpi` is scaled to 0.375 px in `ldpi`, which I think is rounded to 0px. Currently I have just increased width of my resource to 5px, and tested on Galaxy Pocket, and it worked for now. But I would like to sort it out completely with your help. Is my guess correct?

---

The xml where I use it:

```
<LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/info"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@drawable/ui_topbar_bg"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:paddingRight="8dp">
```

`@drawable/ui_topbar_bg` is the image name

Comment: post imageview code. chances of displaying image later..

Comment: @NovusMobile I don't use `ImageView`, as I said, I use image as a `android:background` of the view. I updated the code.

Comment: I am interesting into the your java call. As I mentioned. only chance to get 0  .when you are calling it later one.

Comment: @NovusMobile, I don't use it in Java code. That error appears when system is trying to scale resource itself.

Comment: may be this will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605662/illegalargumentexception-width-and-height-must-be-0-while-loading-bitmap-from

Comment: @NovusMobile, thanks, but I found that already. It is not what I'm asking about

Comment: Why not setting different images in different folder manually ,its not that hard

Comment: @L-X, I know, but that's not an option for me since I'm not professional Photoshop (or like that) user, and can't scale it correctly, and the guy who created `xhdpi` resources won't be paid to scale them to other DPI

Comment: You just have to re-size the images , its fairly easy ,Now I would suggest you to use 2 px wide png , Can I know is your image width is 1px , and if yes then why not use color for background

Comment: @L-X, as said in my question, width is 1 px, and it is not 1 x 1 image. It's height is not 1 px.

Comment: There are no other solutions, your images have to either be at least 2 x 2 px in size or you have to provide additional images for ldpi density.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, thanks. Any link to the official documentation?

Comment: [Supporting Different Densities](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html)  However, there is no official documentation that would specifically mention your issue. It is just matter of simple math, like you already concluded yourself. If you are providing only higher density images, you have to make sure that smallest dimension will be >= 1 px when downscaled. In your current case that is 2 * 0.375 = 0.75 rounded to 1