# I'm a beginner in andriod development and i'm creating a note app that uses local database . Help me to solve this

Tags: android, kotlin

- This text view is used by the recycler view adapter adapter

  ```
          <TextView
           android:id="@+id/note_item"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="200dp"
           android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
           android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
           app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
           tools:text="None" />
  ```
- The following code is applied on the home fragment. It is using a recycler view which is adapting the above view.

  ```
         <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView
             android:id="@+id/card_edit"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="190dp"
             android:background="@color/background_color"
             app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
             app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

               <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/note"
                   android:inputType="text"
                   android:layout_width="488dp"
                   android:layout_height="48dp"
                   android:autofillHints="" />
           </soup.neumorphism.NeumorphCardView>

       <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
           android:id="@+id/addButton"
           style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.Button"
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="60dp"
           android:text="Add Note"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.532"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/card_edit" />

       <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
           android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="400dp"
           android:orientation="vertical"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/addButton"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="259dp"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

       <soup.neumorphism.NeumorphButton
           android:id="@+id/clearButton"
           style="@style/Widget.Neumorph.Button"
           android:layout_width="150dp"
           android:layout_height="40dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
           android:text="Clear Note"
           app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.564"
           app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
           app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/recycler_view"
           app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />
  ```

Here in all the views the width and height are greater than 0 but still I'm getting the same error.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.notelocal, PID: 26959
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: width and height must be > 0
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:877)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:856)
        at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:823)
```

[Error I'm getting]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/deZvX.png

Comment: Add your code and post your error as text, don't link to photos of it.

Comment: Okay Got it, was new to this.

Comment: Your answer might be here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605662/illegalargumentexception-width-and-height-must-be-0-while-loading-bitmap-from

Answer (score 0):

One of your views has a value that 0 or less than 0 on the width or height attributes. Make sure that layoutWidth and layoutHeight is set to a valid integer. It would be best to include the code that you already have or where you suspect the error might be coming from

Comment: I've provided all the views that I had used, there is nothing like what the error is.